# Select option of choice dropdown in a form

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, dropdown, dropdownchoice

I want to select an option in the dropdown from the controller. I am trying with the following piece of code:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SearchAdvancedType());
$form->get('option')->setData($session->get('option'));
```

But it is doing nothing in the dropdown. Nothing is selected when the page loads.

To check if the value was well set I print it using:

```
$form->get('brand')->Data();
```

and the result was a number (it changes depending of what I choosed in the dropdown before).

I need to know the way to select the value of the dropdown properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preset a select option I would pass the value into the form.

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType
{

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('type', 'choice', [
                'required' => true,
                'choices' => ['yes' => 'Yes', 'no' => 'No'],
                'data' => $options['select_option']
            ])
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => null,
            'select_option' => null
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_form';
    }

}
```

Then in your controller, pass the value in;

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MyFormType(), null, ['select_option' => 'no');
```